# Show network name next to wifi icon?

Tags: macos, wifi, catalina, software-recommendation, menu-bar

Is there a way to show the currently connected network name next to the wifi icon in the menu bar?

Comment: Take a look: https://github.com/mutsune/SSIDonMenubar

Comment: @Allan this looks promising, thanks! How do I install it?

Comment: You have to compile it using xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [Display connected Wifi name](https://apps.apple.com/de/app/display-connected-wifi-name/id1526918434?l=en&mt=12) to work perfectly for my needs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several third party solutions. The one I prefer is https://www.intuitibits.com/products/wifi-signal/